# Extracting Text from UITextField

Tags: ios, string, swift, uitextfield

I cannot believe I am asking this but I cannot get this to work in Swift. I have a UITextField which I created dynamically. I am trying to get the text out of the UITextField but here is what I get. See the **note** variable.

What am I doing wrong? [image]

Comment: I think the debugger might just be messing up. Try stepping twice more or test with the following code and break at `if` and you'll see that your variable is fine: `func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) { var tmp :String = textField.text as String; if (false) { println("Hello"); } }`

Comment: What sort of text do you expect the variable to contain? `\x` indicates a hexadecimal escape character.  It could be that most of the characters in your string aren't printable by the debugger.

Comment: It looks like the 3rd character should be a `1`, and the 7th and 8th characters `UH`, and 11-14: `AVSI` and 17: `H` maybe?

Comment: Also provide the original text in the TextField that is causing problem.